# constexpr Offsetof with pointer to member data

Tags: c++

Just before this question is being dismissed for being a duplicate, most (if not all) questions have accepted-answers with outdated / undefined behavior solutions.

#### The question:

Is there a way to get at, compile-time, the offset of a pointer to member data that:

- does not rely on undefined behavior (`nullptr` things)
- Works on the latest gcc version (the `gcc trunk` in compiler explorer)
- works the same way as `offsetof` (or similarly, like the proposed code do).

#### I do not care about:

- non standard-layout types
- msvc compatibility. (it could be nice, but optional)
- having a special case for a specific compiler

#### The issue:

With the trunk version of GCC, the following trick (hack) does not work:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>

namespace detail
{
    // The union stuff is for CLang to avoid creating warnings
    template<typename T, auto MPtr>
    struct offsetof_ptr_helper
    {
        union helper_t { int i = 0;  T value; };
        static constexpr helper_t v = {};
        static constexpr size_t sz = sizeof
        (uint8_t[
            (uint8_t *)&(v.value.*MPtr) -
            (uint8_t *)&v.value
        ]);
    };
}

template<typename T, auto MPtr>
static constexpr size_t offsetof_ptr()
{
    return detail::offsetofptr_helper<T, MPtr>::sz;
}

size_t f()
{
    struct X { char c[10]; int a; };
    return offsetof_ptr<X, &X::a>();
}
```

To be clear, this is a hack using C++98 features and this is not a real surprise that its support is being removed by latest compilers. It works on clang (using the `-std=gnu++17` flag) and gcc (including/up-to g++ 7.3 using the flag `-std=c++17`).

Comment: There is [p0908r0 Offsetof for Pointers to Members](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0908r0.html) proposal on the open-std.org. It seems it is not yet accepted.

Comment: how about `__builtin_offsetof`?

Answer (score 2):

For GCC compiler it's relatively easy to support `constexpr` compile-time calculation of field offset via member pointer. Solution below works without `nullptr`s, `union`s and compile-time struct instantiation and uses `c++17`. Also there are no requirements like construct-ability, small size or being `constexpr`-compatible class/struct

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>
#include <cstdint>

template<typename> struct struct_member_types;
template<typename T, typename F> struct struct_member_types<F T::*> {
  using struct_type = T;
  using member_type = F;
};
template<typename T> using struct_type_t = typename struct_member_types<T>::struct_type;
template<typename T> using member_type_t = typename struct_member_types<T>::member_type;

template<auto field> struct constexpr_field_offset {
  using T = struct_type_t<decltype(field)>;
  using F = member_type_t<decltype(field)>;
  static constexpr const char const_holder = 0;
  static constexpr const T& const_value = reinterpret_cast<const T&>(const_holder);
  static constexpr const F T::* const_field = field;
  static constexpr const char* base_addr = &reinterpret_cast<char const&>(const_value);
  static constexpr const char* field_addr = &reinterpret_cast<char const&>(const_value.*const_field);
  static constexpr const size_t offset = field_addr - base_addr;
};

template<auto field> inline constexpr std::size_t constexpr_field_offset_v = constexpr_field_offset<field>::offset;

struct pod_t {
  uint32_t a;
  uint16_t b;
  uint8_t c;
};

struct __attribute__((__packed__)) tricky_t {
private:
  tricky_t() = delete;
  tricky_t(const tricky_t&) = delete;
  tricky_t(tricky_t&&) = delete;
  ~tricky_t() = delete;
public:
  uint8_t a;
  uint32_t b;
};

int main() {
  static_assert(
    constexpr_field_offset_v<&pod_t::a> == 0,
    "Fail"
  );
  static_assert(
    constexpr_field_offset_v<&pod_t::b> == 4,
    "Fail"
  );
  static_assert(
    constexpr_field_offset_v<&pod_t::c> == 6,
    "Fail"
  );

  static_assert(
    constexpr_field_offset_v<&tricky_t::a> == 0,
    "Fail"
  );
  static_assert(
    constexpr_field_offset_v<&tricky_t::b> == 1,
    "Fail"
  );

  return 0;
}
```

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/r163c1KMP

Comment: This seems to be a deviation from standard C++, where the use of `reinterpret_cast` in disallowed in constant expressions. Indeed, clang rejects this code.

Answer (score 1):

If you jump to the definition of `offsetof` in VS, it gives you this:

```
#define offsetof(s,m) ((::size_t)&reinterpret_cast<char const volatile&>((((s*)0)->m)))
```

Modified a bit to match your problem:

```cpp
template<typename T, auto MPtr>
static constexpr size_t offsetof_ptr()
{
    return ((::size_t) & reinterpret_cast<char const volatile&>((((T*)0)->*MPtr)));
}

size_t f()
{
    struct X { char c[10]; int a; };
    return offsetof_ptr<X, &X::a>();
}
```

This compiles on GCC and MSVC. (It requires C++17 because of the template auto parameter.)

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a real `constexpr` version of this. Despite the fact that you have marked your function `constexpr`, it is not a constant expression because it dereferences a null pointer (undefined behavior), see e.g. [here](https://godbolt.org/z/14YY3WPGe).

Comment: Oh right, OP also said he doesn't want nullptr things. I figured that if this is good enough for the compiler, it might be good enough for someone else 

Comment: It is good enough for that compiler , but since it is undefined behavior, it may not work as intended with other compilers.